# Is a separable extension of an extension field also a separable extension of the base/ground field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

A field is called *separably closed* if the only separable algebraic extension is the trivial one. A *separable closure* of a field $K$ is a separable algebraic extension $K ⊆ K^{\text{sep}}$ with $K^{\text{sep}}$ separably closed.

I want to show that a separable closure $K^{\text{sep}}$ of $K$ is algebraically closed iff $K$ is perfect (i.e. every algebraic extension of $K$ is separable).

I have already proven

> I) Every field has a separable closure.
>
> II) Every pair of separable closures of $K$ is $K$-isomorphic.
>
> III) For every tower $K ⊆ L ⊆ M$ of algebraic extensions we have $$ K⊆ L \text{ and } L ⊆ M  \text{ are both separable } \iff K ⊆ M \text{ is separable.}$$

So here we go. Suppose a separable closure $K^{\text{sep}}$ of $K$ is algebraically closed. Let $L/K$ be an arbitrary algebraic extension. By (I) $L$ has a separable closure $L^{\text{sep}}$. Now *if $L^{\text{sep}}$ were a separable extension of $K$ as well,* then by (II) $K^{\text{sep}}$ and $L^{\text{sep}}$ would be $K$-isomorphic, so we would obtain a tower

$$K ⊆ L ⊆ L^{\text{sep}} \cong_K K^{\text{sep}}. 
$$

of algebraic extensions. As $K ⊆ K^{\text{sep}}$ is separable by definition, (III) implies that $K ⊆ L$ must be too, so $K$ is perfect.

**However**

All we really know is that $L ⊆ L^{\text{sep}}$ is separable. i.e. for all $x ∈ L^{\text{sep}}$ the minimal polynomial $f^x_L ∈ L[X]$ has no multiple roots in $\bar{L}$. This unfortunately does not imply that $f^x_K ∈ K[X]$ has no multiple roots in $\bar{K}$, as $f^x_L$ divides $f^x_K$, not the other way around. Is the reasoning so far correct? If so, how do I show the final ingredient?

Comment: It may be helpful to instead of working with isomorphisms of algebraic closures, work with extending your field embeddings. Eg, if $K$ is perfect, then any algebraic extension $L/K$ lifts to a map $L$ to $K^{sep}$, and vice versa.

Comment: Alright, but that seems to be the other implication, which I have not even addressed yet.

Comment: It seems to me that you never use the fact that $K^{sep}$ is algebraically closed. It implies that $L^{sep}$ embeds in $K^{sep}$ since $L^{sep}/K$ is at least algebraic.

Comment: If L is algebraic it lives in (up to a choice of embedding) the algebraic closure, which you’ve assumed is separable, so L is certain separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do the direction you attempted. I think your difficulty is that you are confused about the following point: generally one fixes a particular algebraic closure of the ground field, and then an extension of that ground field is taken to mean *an extension in that particular choice of algebraic closure*. This just ensures that things like the compositum always "make sense". One can do this because every algebraic extension (living anywhere) admits an inclusion into any particular algebraic closure; in particular all algebraic closures are (non-canonically) isomorphic.

Let $L/K$ algebraic. So either we take $L$ to already be inside of $\bar K = K^{sep}$ (under your assumption) or there is an inclusion of $L$ into $\bar K = K^{sep}$. Either way, $L$ is separable (in the second case it is isomorphic to a separable extension, which is the same thing). So all algebraic extensions are separable, which means $K$ is perfect.

Conversely, if $K$ is perfect then all of its algebraic extensions are separable, so in particular the algebraic closure is separable!

Comment: To me the key comment (“One can do this because ...”) is still somewhat vague. Can you construct this inclusion? Or show that it exists?

Comment: Yes, of course it can be shown to exist. This is usually one of the first things proven in a course on field theory. For instance, see Lang Chapter V section 2 (which precedes the discussion of separability). The general idea is very simple - reducing to the case of single elements, $K(\alpha)$ embeds into $\bar K$ by choosing a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ that lives in $\bar K$ and sending $\alpha$ to it. The referenced section has all the details

Comment: Thanks, I found the proof! (I presume you meant Theorem 2.8.) Wouldn't have thought I would need Zorn, but it does the trick nicely! One question about the converse statement, though: is "the compositum of those separable extensions" even defined for arbitrarily many subfields? Because, to my knowledge, the equivalence "there is a primitive element for the extension $L/K$" ⇔  "there are finitely many intermediate fields $K ⊆ E ⊆ L$" only holds for _finite_ extensions.

Comment: Zorn is necessary because the embedding is really a choice of infinitely many compatible embeddings that are defined on each primitive sub extension.

A compositum is defined for any number of subfields; the compositum of a collection $\{E_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ all contained in a bigger field $M$ is the smallest subfield of $M$ which contains all of the $E_\alpha$'s. Although I'm not sure what primitive element you are talking about since I didn't use one.

Comment: Oh I thought you used that a (finite) extension is separable iff there exists a primitive element iff there are finitely many intermediate fields. But if you don't need to have finitely many subfields to take the compositum, none of that is required.

Comment: Are you, by the way, saying that the algebraic closure is always the compositum of all algebraic extensions? ("the algebraic closure is **then** the compositum ...")

Comment: After you fix an algebraic closure $\bar K/ K$ then it is the compositum of all the algebraic extensions. Actually, I guess I didn't need a compositum since $\bar K$ is itself one of those algebraic extensions. Maybe I should ask: what is your definition of a perfect field? If your definition is "every finite extension is separable" then you would need a compositum (which was sort of my intent above although I left out the word finite).

Comment: My _definition_ is that either char$(K) = 0$ or char$(K)$ is prime and the Frobenius endomorphism is surjective, immediately followed by the _theorem_ that this is equivalent to every **algebraic** extension being separable.. I often run into problems with the 'nonimplication' ($L/K$ algebraic $\nRightarrow L/K$ finite).

Comment: Is it even necessary to talk about composita? After all, $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$, so if $K$ is perfect, then $\bar{K}$ is separable. As there aren't even _algebraic_ extensions $E/\bar{K}$ with $E ≠ \bar{K}$, there will certainly not be any _separable_ algebraic extensions with this property. Thus $\bar{K}$ is separably closed, and hence a separable closure of $K$. As $\bar{K}$ is of course algebraically closed, we are done.

Comment: No it isn’t; I was thinking of taking the composition of all the finite extensions since I had in mind the definition that a perfect field has all its finite extensions separable, but since you have the result about all algebraic extensions being separable already it isn’t necessary (I sort of mixed the two definitions). I will edit that out.